# How to reset the screenshot counter in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, screenshot, reset, counter

In Windows 8, <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> will automatically save a sequentially numbered screenshot at
`%UserProfile%\Pictures\Screenshots`. The file names are of the form
`Screenshot (<index>).png`. However, even if you move/delete existing screenshots the index/counter is not reset. So how do you go about resetting it?

[image: Win8 Screenshots]

Comment: Just a question: Why would I really need this?

Comment: @Matsemann: No-one's forcing you to use it! :) It's just something that is not exposed through the UI and might come in handy *if* you want to start afresh and do not want to bother using a mass renamer to rename the files.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This method requires registry editing, so ***be careful***!

1. Run `regedit` and navigate to:

   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer`
2. Look for a **DWORD** value named `ScreenshotIndex`, which stores the next screenshot's index:

   [image: Win8 Screenshot Index]
3. To reset it, change the value back to **1**

**Note 1:** If you already have existing screenshot files in the `Screenshots` folder, they will *not* be overwritten even after the counter reset. Thus even after resetting the value back to 1, `Screenshot (3).png` will be created in the example above (since screenshots 1 and 2 already exist). If screenshots 1 and 2 are moved/deleted however *before* a fresh screenshot is taken (after the reset of course), the new file will be saved as `Screenshot (1).png`.

**Note 2:** If you want to automate the reset, use the following command:

```
reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer /v ScreenshotIndex /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

You can also save the following as something like `ResetScreenshotIndex.reg`:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer]
"ScreenshotIndex"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: 2nd solution is working for me..